# How should decent_exposure be used to expose related items that may not exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using the decent_exposure gem and have run into a quandry.

I have a model Child that is a child of model Parent, but isn't always called in the context of a Parent - the show method for instance would not be nested.

My Child's controller exposes :parent as well as :children { parent.children } and this works when the index method is called in the context of a Parent but not when the child show method is called without a parental context.

How should this be handled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically would do something like:

```
expose(:child) {params[:id] ? Child.find(params[:id]) : Child.new(params[:child]}
```

This works for the show, update and edit, delete since that would require the ID (/child/1), but the second half of the statement would allow you to also support your new and create.